# Need simple Powershell output appended to Google sheet

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, visual-studio-2013, google-api

I'm having a very hard time with what I feel should be a simple task.  Every week, our team queries VMware vCenter for three pieces of output: VM counts in three different locations.  Here is what it looks like:

```
Name                           Value                           
----                           -----                        
locationA                       1433                              
locationB                       278                            
locationC                       23
```

The information is emailed to our team, as well as some of the higher-ups who like to see the data.  This is all automated with a Powershell script and Windows Task Scheduler running on a server, no problems.

That data is also placed in a Google sheet.  We just append a new row with the date, and copy and paste the data into the three existing columns.  It takes 30 seconds, once a week.  Seems silly given how little time it takes to copy it over to the Google sheet but I really want to automate that last process using Google Sheets API.

I seem to keep finding and persuing what feel are online wild goose chases, in the Google scripting to accessing and editing Google sheets.  I've downloaded and installed the Sheets API libraries, Drive API libraries, the Google .net library, set up the Google developer site, and run through the Google sheets API documentation and OAuth authenticating.  I'm using Visual Studio 2013 because I figured that would play the best with Powershell and calling the .net commands.

I have pretty much no coding experience outside of Powershell (if you can call that coding).  I can't even figure out how to pull the Google sheet, much less do anything to it.  Nothing I've tried is working so far, and for what little time it takes to copy this info manually every week I've already spent so much more time than is probably worth it.  I feel like if I can get a handle on this, that would open the door for further Google automation in the future since we operate with a Google domain.  At any rate, help is very much appreciated.

Here is my latest scripting attempt in Visual Studio:

```
using System;
using Google.GData.Client;
using Google.GData.Spreadsheets;

namespace MySpreadsheetIntegration
{
  class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string CLIENT_ID = "abunchofcharacters.apps.googleusercontent.com";
        string CLIENT_SECRET = "secretnumber";
        string REDIRECT_URI = "https://code.google.com/apis/console";

        OAuth2Parameters parameters = new OAuth2Parameters();
        parameters.ClientId = CLIENT_ID;
        parameters.ClientSecret = CLIENT_SECRET;
        parameters.RedirectUri = REDIRECT_URI;
        parameters.Scope = SCOPE;

        string authorizationUrl = OAuthUtil.CreateOAuth2AuthorizationUrl(parameters);
        Console.WriteLine(https://code.google.com/apis/console);
        Console.WriteLine("Please visit the URL above to authorize your OAuth "
          + "request token.  Once that is complete, type in your access code to "
          + "continue..."));
      parameters.AccessCode = Console.ReadLine();

        OAuthUtil.GetAccessToken(parameters);
      string accessToken = parameters.AccessToken;
      Console.WriteLine("OAuth Access Token: " + accessToken);

        GOAuth2RequestFactory requestFactory =
          new GOAuth2RequestFactory(null, "MySpreadsheetIntegration-v1", parameters);
      SpreadsheetsService service = new SpreadsheetsService("MySpreadsheetIntegration-v1");
      service.RequestFactory = requestFactory;

      var driveService = new DriveService(auth);

      var file = new File();
      file.Title = "VSI - VM Totals by Service TEST";
      file.Description = string.Format("Created via {0} at {1}", ApplicationName, DateTime.Now.ToString());
      file.MimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet";

      var request = driveService.Files.Insert(file);
      var result = request.Fetch();
      var spreadsheetLink = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/GoogleDoc_ID";

      Console.WriteLine("Created at " + spreadsheetLink);


    End Class;
    End Namespace;
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: Does it need to be in Google Sheets?  I would think a simple .csv file that gets appended to that's in a folder sync'd to Google Drive should do the trick nicely, and require much less custom coding

Comment: I agree with @Taegost, if the data is only two columns and three rows then a .csv file would be the easiest way I could think of. Not to mention PowerShells great at working with .csv files.

Comment: I complete agree with you both.  But the existing Google sheet has several sheets of various data and has been around for several years, with several people accessing it.  This scripting option would only update 3 cells of the whole thing.

I have enlisted the help of a group of college Google scriptors in our environment who are also working on this for me.  I appreciate the feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone still following this, I found a solution.  I was going about this entirely the wrong way (or at least a way that I could comprehend).  One solution to my issue was to create a new Google Script that only accessed my email once a week (after we got the report) and teased out everything but the data I was looking for and sent it to the Google spreadsheet.

Here's the script:

```
function SendtoSheet(){
  var threads = GmailApp.search("from:THESENDER in:anywhere subject:THESUBJECTOFTHEEMAILWHICHNEVERCHANGES")[0];
  var message = threads.getMessages().pop()
  var bodytext = message.getBody();
  counts = []
bodytext = bodytext.split('<br>');
  for (var i=0 ; i < bodytext.length; i++){
  line = bodytext[i].split(':');
  if (line.length > 0){
    if (!isNaN(line[1])){counts.push(line[1]);}}}
  var now = new Date()
  counts.unshift(Utilities.formatDate(now, 'EST', 'MM/dd/yyyy'))
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("GoogleDocID")
  sheet = sheet.setActiveSheet(sheet.getSheetByName("Data by Week"))
  sheet.appendRow(counts)
}
```

That Counts array contains the magic to extract the numeric data by breaking up by line breaks and :'s.  Works perfectly.  It didn't involve figuring out how to use Visual Studio, or the .net Google libraries, or editing the running PowerShell script.  Clean and easy.

Hope this helps someone.